# Segmentation fault with local pointer?

Tags: c

This is a function call (so it is just a part of the whole program). It will generate a segmentation fault. I guess it is caused by "pointer being a local variable"?

```
int fileExists(const char *fname){
    int i = 0;
    fseek(fs, sizeof(NODE)*i, SEEK_SET);
    NODE* pointer;
    fread(pointer, sizeof(NODE), 1, fs);
    return 1;
}
```

Updated:

```
typedef struct node {
    char fname[MAX_NAME];
    short fstart;
} NODE;

int findStart (const char *fname){
    fs = fopen("Directory", "w+");
    NODE* pointer = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numberNodes;i++){
        fseek(fs, sizeof(NODE)*i, SEEK_SET);
        fread(pointer, sizeof(NODE), 1, fs);
        if(strcmp(pointer->fname, fname)==0)
            return pointer->fstart;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So if I want to run through the nodes in the directory file and find the "fstart" of the right node, can I achieve that without the need of free-ing the memory allocated to "pointer"?

Comment: You probably should make that edit a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
NODE* pointer;
fread(pointer, sizeof(NODE), 1, fs);
```

You never allocated any space for `NODE`.

```
NODE* pointer = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
```

However, I'm not sure what the purpose is since you're immediately leaving the function. Don't forget to later `free` the pointer.

Based on the name of the function `fileExists`, all you probably need to do is to just try to open the file, check whether it succeeds or fails, then return. All the code here is unnecessary.

Something like this will (almost) do what I think you want:

```
int fileExists(const char *fname){
    FILE *file = fopen(fname,"r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return 0;
    fclose(file);
    return 1;
}
```

**EDIT : Answer to the new question.**

To completely avoid the `malloc` in the first place you can just put `NODE` as a local variable on the stack:

```
int findStart (const char *fname){
    fs = fopen("Directory", "w+");
    NODE node;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numberNodes;i++){
        fseek(fs, sizeof(NODE)*i, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&node, sizeof(NODE), 1, fs);
        if(strcmp(node.fname, fname)==0)
            return node.fstart;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am immediately leaving the function because I wanted to simplify it and extract only the codes which generate the problems.
NODE* pointer = malloc(sizeof(NODE)); --> Doing that will help but I dont understand why I need that. Can you help clarify my misunderstanding?

Comment: In your original code `pointer` doesn't point anywhere valid because it's not initialized. When `fread` tries to write to it, it crashes. The `malloc`, will allocate memory and return the pointer. Now `fread` will write to the memory allocated by the `malloc`. Also be aware that when you allocate memory like this, you need to free it later or you will have a memory leak.

Comment: Mysticial, I have updated the codes. Can I achieve that without the need of free-ing the memory allocated to "pointer"? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do it without using `malloc()` at all. It's actually preferable in this case since you won't have to deal with freeing it.

Comment: How can I achieve that without freeing it?